# F# Computation Expressions and Return statement

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

On the Try F# website they give an example of a computation expression:

```
type Age =
| PossiblyAlive of int
| NotAlive

type AgeBuilder() =
    member this.Bind(x, f) =
        match x with
        | PossiblyAlive(x) when x >= 0 && x <= 120 -> f(x)
        | _ -> NotAlive
    member this.Delay(f) = f()
    member this.Return(x) = PossiblyAlive x

let age = new AgeBuilder()

let willBeThere (a:int) (y:int) =
  age { 
    let! current = PossiblyAlive a
    let! future = PossiblyAlive (current + y)

    return future
  }
```

which seems a bit like the standard Maybe monad found in Haskell.

However, in true Haskell form I would want to use return for the two lines:

```
let! current = PossiblyAlive a
let! future = PossiblyAlive (current + y)
```

to be:

```
let! current = return a
let! future = return (current + y)
```

however it doesn't work.  The closest I get to is:

```
let! current = age.Return a
let! future = age.Return (current + y)
```

but this looks dirty.  Is there any way to use `return` without using the computation builders function explicitly?

Comment: Your code works for me - what is the error you get?

Comment: no error - its about computation expression syntax and the "return" statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a nested expression:

```
let! current = age { return a }
let! future = age { return (current + y) }
```

although you could just use `let` instead:

```
let current = a
let future = current + y
```

Be aware that this builder breaks the monad laws since

`return 150 >>= return` is not the same as `return 150`

Comment: Perfect... answered my question - and also confirmed my suspicion that there was something "iffy" about the "Return" definition not doing the bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at this problem in more detail and I think I have found a reasonable alternative to using the `age { return <expr> }` syntax that Lee shows in his answer.

My main beef with this syntax is that we are already in the `age` monad therefore any `return` statement within the body ought to resolve automatically to `age.Return`. However, fixing this is probably of very low priority for the F# team, because the workaround is extremely simple.

My alternative is to overload the `Bind` method with a function which takes a value which it then lifts; then sends this lifted value to the other `Bind` function:

```
type Age =
| PossiblyAlive of int
| NotAlive

type AgeBuilder() =
    let reasonableAge (x:int) = x >= 0 && x <= 120

    member __.Return x = 
        if reasonableAge x then PossiblyAlive x else NotAlive

    member __.Bind(x:Age, f) =
        match x with
        | PossiblyAlive x when reasonableAge x -> f x
        | _ -> NotAlive

    member this.Bind(x:int, f) =
        this.Bind(this.Return(x), f)

let age = new AgeBuilder()

let willBeThere (a:int) (y:int) =
    age { 
        let! current = a
        let! future = (current + y)
        return future
    }
```